# 'Hidden' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a small personal project to make a responsive website using Material-UI.

I am using react and have used create-react-app to start the project.  I have copied code from material-ui for a [responsive drawer](https://v4.mui.com/components/drawers/).  I keep getting an error message on the `Hidden` tag. It doesn't prevent the app from running, but I find it to be very annoying.  I can add `//@ts-nocheck` but this stops all error highlighting in the file, and `//@ts-ignore` which is creating a `</>` tag.

Is there a way to just get rid of this?

The error message is:

```
'Hidden' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<HiddenProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<HiddenProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<HiddenProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/ciara/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/4.9/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)`
```

Comment: It's old version of docs. Try this https://mui.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs, `Hidden` has been deprecated https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#hidden

Answer (score 0):

use React Types version ^17.0.38

"@types/react": "^17.0.38"